# How to test Ajax responses with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, capybara

I have an ajaxified link in a Rails app that, when clicked, results in changes to the DOM.

I'm using Capybara to test for this DOM change. The test is failing, but in the browser this user interaction results in the expected DOM change.

I suspect the test is not waiting for the ajax request to complete. However, I had understood that `expect(page).to have_selector` does wait until said element exists.

What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way to test this interaction?

The code is as follows:

```
#objects/show.html.erb
...
<div class='like-container'>
  <%= render partial: "shared/like_button" %>
</div>
...


#shared/like_button
<% if current_user.likes? @likable %>
  <%= link_to 'Unlike', 
    unlike_path(#params),
    id:"#{@likable.class.name.underscore }_#{ @likable.id }_like", 
    class: "unlike-btn",
    method: :delete, 
    remote: true 
    %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Like', 
    like_path(#params), 
    id: "#{@likable.class.name.underscore }_#{ @likable.id }_like",
    class: "like-btn",
    method: :post, 
    remote: true 
    %>
<% end %>


#likes/create.js
$('#<%= @likable.class.name.underscore %>_<%= @likable.id %>_like').replaceWith('<%= j render partial: "shared/like_button" %>');


#likes/destroy.js 
$('#<%= @likable.class.name.underscore %>_<%= @likable.id %>_like').replaceWith('<%= j render partial: "shared/like_button" %>');


#user_likes_object_spec.rb
feature 'likes object' do
  before :each do
    @object = create :object
    @user   = create :user
    login_as @user
    visit object_path @object
  end

  scenario 'it creates and then destroys like when clicked', js: true do
    expect(page).to have_link "Like", href: like_path(#params)
    click_link 'Like'
    # the test is failing on the following line
    # Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector("a.unlike-btn")
    # expected to find css "a.unlike-btn" but there were no matches
    expect(page).to have_selector("a.unlike-btn")
    click_link 'Unlike'
    expect(page).to have_selector("a.like-btn")
  end
end
```

Why isn't `expect(page).to have_selector("a.unlike-btn")` waiting until this DOM element exists?

Comment: add a sleep(3) before the expectation.

Comment: Thanks @ArupRakshit, won't this make the tests brittle if, for example, the ajax occasionally takes 4 seconds to complete? What is the correct way to detect a DOM change in Capybara?

Comment: that I said to test if it solves or not. After that I can give same advice as you commented in the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://blog.tomoyukikashiro.me/post/things-to-be-aware-of-when-change-capybara_default_wait_time/) explains setting a default wait time by putting:

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 10
```

into your RSpec config file.

[This article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara) explains actually waiting for the DOM to completely update.

Comment: Thank you, the `wait` option is very useful. `have_selector('a.unlike-btn',  wait: 10). Turns out I also had a user permissions issue that was preventing the expected response, but this helped me to identify the problem. Thanks !